# List within list Sorting issue in Java

Tags: java, list, sorting

I am trying to sort a `List<List<Integer>>`.
The internal list will have 3 values. (X-coordinate, Y-coordinate, Start/end)
Now while it works for most of the cases, the sorting fails for a specific case.

The code I used for sorting is:

```
arr.sort((a,b) -> {
            if(a.get(0)!=b.get(0)){
                return a.get(0) - b.get(0);
            }
            else{
                return  (a.get(2)==0?-a.get(1):a.get(1)) - (b.get(2)==0?-b.get(1):b.get(1));
            }
        });
```

The logic behind it is:
If x value is not equal we sort them on the basis of x.
if equal then:
if both start then on basis of height in descending order.
if both end then on basis of height in ascending order.
else whichever was the start.

The start is shown as 0 and end as 1.

The example in which is failing is:
arr:

`[[1, 10000, 0], [10001, 10000, 1], [2, 9999, 0], [10001, 9999, 1]]`

Output:

```
[[1, 10000, 0], [2, 9999, 0], [10001, 10000, 1], [10001, 9999, 1]]
```

while the expected sorting is:

```
[[1, 10000, 0], [2, 9999, 0], [10001, 9999, 1], [10001, 10000, 1]]
```

Can you please help me find out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't use `==` and `!=` to compare two `Integer`s. You should use `equals`. They're objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working as intended. Since in your code for the comparison between `[10001, 9999, 1]` and `[10001, 10000, 1]`, it will go in the `else` statement and since `a.get(2)` and `b.get(2)` both are non zero, the `else` statement will be reduced to `b.get(1) - a.get(1)`, which sorts in descending order. Therefore, it will sort in the order `[10001, 10000, 1]` and then `[10001, 9999, 1]`.

Also, boxed integers (`Integer`) should not be compared using `==` or `!=` operators as they will be compared by reference. Instead, `equals` method should be used.

The second else condition should subtract y of b from y of a. Something like this:

```
(a,b) -> {
        if(!a.get(0).equals(b.get(0))){
            return a.get(0) - b.get(0);
        }
        else{
            return (a.get(2).equals(0)?-a.get(1):a.get(1)) - (b.get(2).equals(0)?-b.get(1):b.get(1));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I used it too. It is not working. Is this code giving correct results for the above-mentioned case to you?
Also, I have updated the question with this code. I mistakenly added the other one.

Comment: yeah, the second problem is the use of != to compare boxed integers. They should be compared using `equals` method. I will update the answer.

Comment: Changing it to equals worked!!! 
I needed to change it in the first IF as well. Thank you much!!!
You can update the answer and I am Sure gonna mark it as answer!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the original sort code is very hard to read and don't match your expectation. 
I change it to :

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Integer>> list = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1, 10000, 0),
                Arrays.asList(10001, 10000, 1), Arrays.asList(2, 9999, 0)
        ,Arrays.asList(10001, 9999, 1)
        , Arrays.asList(10001, 9999, 0));

        Collections.sort(list, (a,b) -> {
            if(!a.get(0).equals(b.get(0))){
                return a.get(0) - b.get(0);
            }
            else{
                if (b.get(2).equals(a.get(2))) {
                    if (a.get(2) == 0) {
                        return Integer.compare(b.get(1), a.get(1)); //start, descending
                    } else {
                        return Integer.compare(a.get(1), b.get(1)); // ascending
                    }
                } else {
                    return  a.get(2) == 0 ? -1 : 1; // 0 first
                }
            }
        });

        System.out.println(list); // [[1, 10000, 0], [2, 9999, 0], [10001, 9999, 0], [10001, 9999, 1], [10001, 10000, 1]]

    }
```

Hope it helps